# Transparent background iframe

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

*The answers for already  questions like this doesn't produce the required output.*

I have

```
<iframe src="http://www.foxyform.com/form.php?id=541803&sec_hash=027132f38b1" frameborder=0  allowTransparency="true" style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);"></iframe>
```

And a jquery code(which probably is wrong :P)

```
$('iframe').contents().find('body').append('style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);" />');
```

Basically I want the background to be transparent so my webpage's background image becomes visible. To achieve this I need to add this into the iframe's body tag:

```
style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

The above jquery code used isn't working to get the desired results. Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can only edit the iframe style if it is on the same domain.
Bearing that in mind, try

```
background:transparent;
```

Comment: then why are you trying to edit the iframe style using JS then?

Comment: Its possible only (as far as I know) using Jquery (and JS obviously)

Comment: its possible only if the Protocols, domains, and ports match the iframe you are embedding. If you see here http://jsfiddle.net/2UVUk/ and then look at the console you will see a SecurityError

Comment: @smistry You mean in the jsfiddle console or browser console? I don't see the security error. Is this still the same with being possible only on the same protocal+domain+port?